# Why doesn't 100vh fill whole page?

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I'm currently using React and I'm having issues getting a div to equal 100% of the height of the page. Originally, I had an issue with there always being about 24px of empty space above the body. I couldn't fit it no matter what. I eventually used this on my app.css (a reset)

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  outline: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  background: transparent;
}
```

It fixed the issue, but still, a measurement of 100% or 100vh doesn't actually equal 100% of the total view. Here's a screenshot of the page:

https://gyazo.com/3407b6bd0032f402f3bb97acdb725e40

The blue div is a div that fills 100vh. Yet, it doesn't fully fill the page. I tried 100% as well.

Blue div:

```
.loginWrapper {
  margin-left: 260px;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #29B6F6;
}
```

I noticed that the `html` had this styling on it, yet even when removed no changes were noticeable:

```
html {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

If someone could please explain this phenomenon, I would be very grateful. If you need any extra information, just let me know. Thanks!

Comment: We need your full page's HTML and CSS to find the problem.  There's no red flags here in what you've provided.

Comment: if you give us your website link or any whare for check this issue or update   this Q with full code .

Comment: `100vh` is always ***100% of viewport height*** in browsers that support `vh`. [`box-sizing`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_box-sizing.asp) sets what should be included when calculating an element's size (`width` and `height`).

Answer (score 3):

You will have to reset the basics margin and padding if applied from html and other top level tags.

```
body, html {margin: 0;padding: 0;}
```

Or just use something like reset.css

http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/